# Selenium Dom values are not updated

Tags: selenium

I am seeing a problem in Selenium with IE6/8 that is giving me some bad time. The problem is that the DOM window properties are not updated after actions are done and always return the default values.

To give you couple of examples:

1. Browser is first launched in normal size (`document.body.clientHeight = 500px`). After I do window maximizing, the property stays `500px`!
2. Scroll top offset (`document.body.scrollop`) is initially `0`, I then do scrolling, when I access the property it is till `0`!

Has anyone seen this problem before or might know what is causing it?

Comment: can you put how you are accessing the browser as I think that *may* be the issue. Selenium wraps the window object which can cause a problem when doing normal JavaScript DOM accesses

Comment: Here...

ISelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", destinationUri.AbsoluteUri.ToString());

selenium.GetEval("window.scrollBy(0,50)");

int offset = Convert.ToInt32(selenium.GetEval("documnet.body.scrollTop"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the Window and document object in Selenium test you need to put `this.browserbot.getUserWindow()`. It gives you access to the page that Selenium is working on.

```
int offset = Convert.ToInt32(selenium.GetEval("this.browserbot.getUserWindow().document.body.scrollTop"));
```